# List substring filter elements on a second list

Tags: python-3.x, list, filtering

Found this code that addressed my problem, however I only partly understand how it works, sounds silly but I could use some explanations, beginner and I do not 100% get it how it works:

```
matchers = ['abc','def']
matching = [s for s in my_list if any(xs in s for xs in matchers)]
```

`s for s`: guess s represents elements in my_list going through this list elements / iterating

`xs in s for xs in matchers`: guess this is saying any elements of matchers found in the elements of my_list

Any explanations are very welcome and will be really grateful for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: I guess I got it: 
 XS means: value of the matchers'  elements,
 xs in s means: value of the matchers' elements value found in the value of the my_list element's value

Comment: That is a python feature named [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

```
matchers = ['abc','def']
```

^ Means that this is what it will look for.

```
if any(xs in s for xs in matchers)
```

^ If there is any one of the strings in Matchers found in My_List, then it will find it. There is not much to it, you got it in your original post.